# Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am getting the following error when i connected my ipad device in other simulator app is working fine

[image]

My app settings:

[image]

Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new certificate and provisioning profile out of it solves the problem most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

**Check the following :**

**1.** Check that your current **"Bundle Identifier"** is same as your current **"Provisioning Profile"** name in **"Code Signing Identity"**.

**2.** In **"Code Signing identity block"** - Check Debug AND Distribution have the same **"Code Signing Information"**. Try to keep the **"Code Signing Information"** same in all the Blocks.

**3.** Try to Download the **"Provisioning Profile"** again and double click on the profile. Then use that newly downloaded profile in your **"Code Signing Identity"**.

**4.** Try to Download the **"Certificate"** again from the **"developer.apple.com"** and double click on the certificate. (It worked in my case)

Then **"Clean"** the project and click on **"Build for Archive"**.
Hope your code will be archived perfectly.

Comment: Vin Could you help me to find "Bundle identifier"?

Comment: @AdnanKhan : Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to be registered as an Apple Developer ($99 a year) in order to test your software on an iOS device. For more information, refer to https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because:

1. You do not have a valid Apple Developer Program membership. If this is the case than you need to enroll in the program.
2. You don't have the certificate installed or a valid private key for the certificate. If this is the case you can either:
   a) Restore the certificate from a backup, or b)create and install a new certificate keypair.

All these problems and solutions are explained in the excellent [Apple Technical note TN220](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html)